# Three routes for one verb in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to get the following three routes to work:

- `GET /api/category` - list all categories
- `GET /api/category/1` - get details about category 1
- `GET /api/category/1/questions` - get questions from category 1

I am having trouble getting this routing to work.

My `CategoryController` has the following three method definitions:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Get() {}
public Category Get(int id) {}
public IEnumerable<QuestionSummary> GetQuestions(int id) {}
```

How can I get these to match and not conflict with eachother? We have used AttributeRouting in other parts of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "SubResource",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{categoryId}/{action}"
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and your controller:

```
public class CategoryController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Get() 
    {
        ...
    }

    public Category Get(int id) 
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<QuestionSummary> Questions(int categoryId) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

ASP.NET Web API 2 makes this scenario much easier as it allows for [`attribute based routing`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

I am sure Microsoft will eventually get it right (the way [`ServiceStack`](http://www.servicestack.net/) does it). Hopefully in ASP.NET Web API 3 they will introduce message based routing and they will have done a REST framework the right way - it will be message based and routing will be done on those messages.

Comment: You are technically correct, but I couldn't get it to work until I used different names for the `id` field in the different routes. Very un-intuitive, but hey, it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have multiple methods for the same verb on the same controller unless you use "action".

I guess you can handle your 3 routes using 3 different controller as long as you register those in the proper order.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route1",
    routeTemplate: "/api/category/{id}/questions",
    controllerType: typeof(YourController1)
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route2",
    routeTemplate: "/api/category/{id}",
    controllerType: typeof(YourController2)
    );  

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Route3",
    routeTemplate: "/api/category",
    controllerType: typeof(YourController3)
    );
```

Comment: How would you use "action" in this case? How would I disable the existing routes for this controller when using the definitions above?

Comment: Using action you have to modify the rout template. For ex: /api/category -> /api/category/list where list is the action. I understand is not feasible if you already delivered your api; I just mentioned as an option to handle multiple methods for same verb on the same controller.